# This is very easy but i am struck with one

Tags: calculus

This is findind limit calculus one. This would be very easy but i never factor high degrees. can anyone show me how to factor it.

lim((x^5-32)/(x-2),x=2)

lim((x^5-2^5)/(x-2),x=2)

Comment: This is a programming site, not a math site. But the answer should be 80.  Use L'Hospital's rule.  :)

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is unnecessary here since `x-2` divides evenly into `x^5-32`. Have you ever done polynomial long division? Google it and you'll be surprised how easy it is to do the factoring in this case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maths, belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Use WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28x^5+-+2^5%29+%2F+%28x+-+2%29%2C+x+%3D+2)

Comment: @mbratch I get the same answer, but it took me about 10 times as long to do it your way. :P

Comment: @John, that's only because you're not practiced at polynomial factoring. And after all, your question did say, "please show me how to factor it", so I could only assume that was the approach you wanted to take. I have nothing against L'Hospital's rule to get a quick answer, but it's good to understand what's going on. :)

Comment: @mbratch You got me. You've exposed that my polynomial long division skills are rusty. Yet I still managed to get the answer without getting out pencil and paper. Maybe that means that polynomial long division was unnecessary for this problem? :) There's almost always more than one way to do things, and if that's the case, then *no* particular method is necessary.

Comment: No worries. It's good to learn multiple methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John suggested in the comments above: when x-->2 we handle a limit of type 0/0. In order to calculate it we use the derivative of the numerator and a derivative  of the denominator:

```
f'(X^5-2^5) = 5x^4
----------    ----
f'(x-2)     = 1
```

if we'll substitute x with 2 we'll get:

```
5*2^4
----- = 80
1
```

Comment: i was doing it without using derivative..

Comment: @PenpaGyaltsen via polynomial division (I did this in my head so hope I have it right): `(x^5-32)/(x-2)` is `x^4+2x^3+4x^2+8x+16`. Substitute `x = 2` and you get `80` just like alfasin got. :)